# Judging prime number with MIPS code using QtSpim

Tags: assembly, mips

This MIPS assembly code is need to judge the number is prime or not.

But it doesn't complete yet.

Here's my code:

```
.text
    .globl  main

# INPUT
main:
        li  $v0, 4
        la  $a0, input
        syscall

        li  $v0, 5
        syscall
        move    $s0, $v0        # $s0 = input

# CHECK IF INPUT > 1 (write something in here)
L1: 


# FOR LOOP INPUT > 1 (write something in here)
L2:


#PRINT OUTPUT (FALSE)
L3:
        li      $v0, 4
        la      $a0, false
        syscall

        j Exit

#PRINT OUTPUT (TRUE)
L4:
        li      $v0, 4
        la      $a0, true
        syscall

        j Exit

#EXIT
Exit:
        li      $v0, 10
        syscall 

.data
input:  .asciiz "Input: "
true:   .asciiz "True"
false:  .asciiz "False"
```

Here's the example:

> Example 1
>
> Input: 1
>
> False
>
> Example 2
>
> Input: 2
>
> True
>
> Example 3
>
> Input: 3
>
> True
>
> Example 4
>
> Input: 4
>
> False

What code should I write in **L1** and **L2** field to make it can judge prime number?

I using [QtSpim](http://spimsimulator.sourceforge.net/) to run this MIPS assembly code.

Comment: One possible (though perhaps not very efficient) way of doing this would be to loop from `2..N-1` and verify that `(N % i) != 0`. MIPS has a `div` instruction that gives you the remainder in the `HI` register.

Comment: Can you write it in MIPS code @Michael

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [MIPS Assembly code to find all the prime numbers below an inputted number](//stackoverflow.com/q/40246994), but that loops over multiple integers to test.  (And the answer doesn't provide a complete working version, it's a buggy question with an answer that just points out the bug.  But it does show how to use `div` / `mfhi` to test the remainder.)